# Subclassing QLabel and use it in QWidget class

Tags: c++, qt, subclass, qlabel

When i try to put QLabel in QWidget class its not work properly (no hover event or click event only the label pixmap is show) only the last instance work properly, when not use set parent, it create in new window for each label but its work correctly

this gif show the problem:

https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7TKKmZSISGXN4Opq/giphy.gif

this is QLabel subclass header:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QLabel>
class myLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myLabel();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *);
    void enterEvent(QEvent *);
    void leaveEvent(QEvent *);


signals :
    void labelClicked();
    void enterSignal();
    void leaveEventSignal();

private:

};
```

this class to make a labelButton:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget> 
#include "mylabel.h"
class labelButton : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    labelButton();

    //some functions

private slots:
    //slots

private:
   //private member
};
```

and this the class that i want to use the labelButtons in:

```
#include <QWidget> 
#include "labelbutton.h"

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;

    labelButton *b_1, *b_2, *b_3;

};
```

here is widget.cpp:

```
   Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    b_1 = new labelButton;
    b_1->setParent(this);
    b_1->moveButton(70, 100);
    //some functions to initialize the labelButton
    b_1->show();

    //-----------------------

    b_2 = new labelButton;
    b_2->setParent(this);
    b_2->moveButton(70, 200);
    //some functions to initialize the labelButton
    b_2->show();

    //-----------------------

    b_3 = new labelButton;
    b_3->setParent(this);
    b_3->moveButton(70, 300);
    //some functions to initialize the labelButton
    b_3->show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what's exactly non working?

Comment: in widget.cpp when create instance of labelButton i made 3 labelButton, the first two only show label image with no hover or click(it should change the pixmap of the label when its hover or clicked) the last one work correctly

Comment: Please reduce the source code to a minial, complete, compilable example. You're not including the source for your labels.

Comment: this gif show the problem
https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7TKKmZSISGXN4Opq/giphy.gif

Comment: Error is probably in your actual code, ie. methods.

Comment: i think the error in labelButton base class (QWidget) i tried change it with QLabel but its not shows the buttons, i think its related to parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here its work, the problem was in passing the parent
i made a function that take a widget and set buttons parent from the function value

```
b_1 = new labelButton;
//b_1->setParent(this); 
b_1->setParentFunc(this);
b_1->moveButton(70, 100);
//some functions to initialize the labelButton
// b_1->show();
```

in labelButton:

```
void labelButton::setParentFunc(QWidget *p)
{
    myParent = p;
}

mLabel_1->setParent(myParent); // myParent instead of this
```

Comment: What's wrong with just doing this the usual way, by giving parent pointer to constructor?